# Get value according to one property of objects inside a array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

```js
function chartdata(arr = [], n) {
    const data = [
        {
          "Alcohol": 1,
          "Malic Acid": 13.87,
        },
        {
          "Alcohol": 1,
          "Malic Acid": 14.87,
        },
        {
          "Alcohol": 1,
          "Malic Acid": 12.7,
        },
        {
          "Alcohol": 2,
          "Malic Acid": 11.97,
        },
        {
          "Alcohol": 2,
          "Malic Acid": 13.7,
        },
        {
          "Alcohol": 2,
          "Malic Acid": 12.81,
        },
        {
          "Alcohol": 3,
          "Malic Acid": 11.87,
        },
        {
          "Alcohol": 3,
          "Malic Acid": 13.7,
        },
        {
          "Alcohol": 3,
          "Malic Acid": 12.87,
        }
        ]
        
        
        
      let alcohol = [];
      let malicAcidAvg = [];

      const malicAcidArr1 = [];
      const malicAcidArr2 = [];
      const malicAcidArr3 = [];
        
        let total1 = 0;
        let total2 = 0;
        let total3 = 0;
        let temAlArr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          temAlArr.push(arr[i].Alcohol);
          if (arr[i].Alcohol === n) {
            malicAcidArr1.push(arr[i]["Malic Acid"]);
          } else if (arr[i].Alcohol === n + 1) {
            malicAcidArr2.push(arr[i]["Malic Acid"]);
          } else {
            malicAcidArr3.push(arr[i]["Malic Acid"]);
          }
        }

        alcohol.push(...new Set(temAlArr));

        for (let i = 0; i < malicAcidArr1.length; i++) {
          total1 += malicAcidArr1[i];
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < malicAcidArr2.length; i++) {
          total2 += malicAcidArr2[i];
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < malicAcidArr3.length; i++) {
          total3 += malicAcidArr3[i];
        }
        total1 = total1 / malicAcidArr1.length + 1;
        total2 = total2 / malicAcidArr2.length + 1;
        total3 = total3 / malicAcidArr3.length + 1;
        malicAcidAvg.push(total1, total2, total3);
        }
       chartdata(data, 1);
```

I wanted the average of “Malic Acid” for each class(Alcohol property) but dynamically and don't want to hard code it If someone knows the answer please share. In the end I want twor arrays alcohol and malicAcidArr   and what they are going to have is for alcohol I've done but for malicAcidArr I need help and malicAcidArr will have average of values of Malic Acid according to alcohol means If alcohol=1 than I want all Malic acid values and get the average of those values and than push it in malicAcidArr   and I want this for all the alcohol values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a serializable data interchange format intended to be machine and human readable. Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals"_

Comment: `ReferenceError: arr is not defined`

Comment: I've copied this data from my JSON file

Comment: Your question is unrelated to JSON. You have a JavaScript literal. It doesn't play a role where the data comes from. What is your question? You described what you want and you posted a buggy code, but you didn't ask a question. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @jabaa I'm sorry for posting a buggy code but this is why I need help because I am unable to write proper code. The question here is how I can write a code where the mallic     AcidArr will get it's value dynamically. The issue I'm facing here that I've hard coded everything and that where I need help

Comment: You should debug your code and fix typos before you ask a question. Then you should ask a specific programming question. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/): _StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Concept**

1. Group the data by Alcohol value.
2. Extract alcohol to its own array, and average malic acid values to its own array.

**Code**

```js
const data=[{Alcohol:1,"Malic Acid":13.87},{Alcohol:1,"Malic Acid":14.87},{Alcohol:1,"Malic Acid":12.7},{Alcohol:2,"Malic Acid":11.97},{Alcohol:2,"Malic Acid":13.7},{Alcohol:2,"Malic Acid":12.81},{Alcohol:3,"Malic Acid":11.87},{Alcohol:3,"Malic Acid":13.7},{Alcohol:3,"Malic Acid":12.87}];
// Step 1: Group the data by Alcohol value.
let groupedData = [];
data.forEach(d => {
  let found = false;
  groupedData.forEach(gd => {
    if (gd['Alcohol'] === d['Alcohol']){
      gd['Malic Acid'].push(d['Malic Acid']);
      found = true;
    }
  });
  if (!found){
    groupedData.push({'Alcohol':d['Alcohol'],'Malic Acid':[d['Malic Acid']]});
  }
});
// Step 2: Extract alcohol to its own array, and average malic acid values to its own array.
let alcohol = [];
let malicAcidArr = [];
groupedData.forEach(gd => {
  alcohol.push(gd['Alcohol']);
  malicAcidArr.push(gd['Malic Acid'].reduce((prev,curr)=>prev+curr)/gd['Malic Acid'].length);
});
// See results
console.log(alcohol);
console.log(malicAcidArr);
```